# Unwanted <head /> appearing in PHP generated XML - why?

Tags: php, xml

The PHP code is this:-

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
echo "<example>\n";
echo "</example>";
```

The result is this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" /?>
<head/><example>
</example>
```

Why is this < head/ > tag appearing? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: _Where_ is the `<head>` appearing? Are you inspecting the output in your browser console, or viewing the page source? View the page source, as your console may be mistaking this for HTML and showing you an empty `<head>` tag.

Comment: It's in the source, that's where I was viewing it.

Comment: The same PHP code on a different server does not produce the unwanted Head tag.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably, you are sending the XML with a HTML content-type, and there is a HTML post processor like *mod_pagespeed* or *cloudflare* taking place between this PHP script and the browser.

You should try sending the XML with a proper content type like `application/xml`:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know mod_pagespeed would do that - I was looking around through PHP ini directives for some old "HTML autofix" configuration, thinking there might have been something like that from the days of magic_quotes_gpc, register_globals, et al.